# Redimensionar imagen con QPixmap

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Estoy tratando de cambiar el tamaño de la imagen pero no funciona, este es el código:

```
 pixi = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(image)
 pixi.scaledToWidth(150)
 pixi.scaledToHeight(150)
 self.label.resize(150,150)

 self.label.setPixmap(pixi)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero simplemente se mantiene con las mismas dimensiones originales.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`QPixmap.scaledToHeight`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#scaledToHeight) y [`QPixmap.scaledToWidth`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#scaledToWidth) no realizan el escalado *"in-place"*, **retornan una nueva instancia de `QPixmap`**. Debería por tanto asignar la salida del método a una nueva variable: `scaled_pixi = pixi.scaledToWidth(150)`.

Por otro lado, si usas`QPixmap.scaledToHeight` la imagen se escala para ajustar el alto especificado, ajustando automáticamente el ancho 
 para mantener la relación de aspecto de la imagen y por tanto será mayor o menor al alto especificado en base a esta relación. Ocurre lo mismo con  `QPixmap.scaledToWidth`, por lo que no tiene sentido que uses ambas simultáneamente.

```
pixi = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(image).scaledToWidth(150)
self.label.setPixmap(pixi)
```

Si necesitas escalar la imagen a un alto y ancho dados sin mantener la relación de aspecto usa [`QPixmap.scaled`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#scaled-1):

```
pixi = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(image).scaled(150, 150)
self.label.setPixmap(pixi)
```

Si deses que la imagen se escale manteniendo la relación de aspecto pero que se mantenga dentro de un rectángulo de altura y ancho dados solo tienes que usar el parámetro `aspectRatioMode` de `QPixmap.scaled` (por defecto es `Qt.IgnoreAspectRatio`):

```
pixi = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(image).scaled(150, 150, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
```

esto hace que para una imagen original de 300 x 200 quede escalada a 150 x 100, o una de 200 x 300 se escale a 100 x 150.

Comment: @Revsky01 no se cual era tu intención inicial, si querías redimensionar manteniendo o no el aspect ratio. Por si quieres redimensionar tu imagen para que ocupe como máximo 150 x 150 pero manteniendo la relación de aspecto (y evitar que se deforme por tanto) he editado la respuesta añadiéndolo al final. Un saludo.

Comment: si queria que se mantuviera el aspect-ratio muchas gracias por la respuesta